# AS3: How do i draw shapes in my own class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

I'm very new on AS3. I would like to create a shape as i defined in my own constructor class.

It should create a shape when class was created. (Constructor)

I commented my want in following code :

**ballShape class**

```
public class ballShape {

        public function ballShape() {
            // define shape properties.
            // create shape and put that in x = 0, y = 0 
        }

    }
```

Any helps would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this while extending your class to Shape or Sprite

Here's your code

```
public class ballShape extends Sprite {

    public function ballShape() {
        // define shape properties. The graphics object is already added to your Sprite, no need to manually addChild() this object.
        graphics.beginFill(color, alpha); // you can begin a fill with this method, there are also methods to start a bitmap fill, gradient fill. 
        graphics.drawRect( x, y, width, height ); // draw a shape
        graphics.endFill();
    }

}
```

While Shape can have the same functionality to draw shapes and lines, I chose Sprite, because:

- You will have interactivity and be able to dispatch events from that class
- You will have a set of useful properties that Sprite has.

For more info on the Graphics class, please refer to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I'm trying to create a shape with your approach, you can see my codes in third party site in [here](http://textsave.de/VaK). It trace something out correctly after create an instance from `ballShape`. But doesn't show any shapes after run.

Comment: when you create the ballShape object (var ball:ballShape = new ballShape() ) you need to add that object to the display list ( addChild(ball) );
Otherwise the ballShape creates a shape, but the ballShape itself is not added to the stage.